# I can't establish connection in datastax message: Cannot open connection

Tags: cassandra, localhost, datastax, cql, multipeer-connectivity

[I have this problem with the connection because I have tried every way and it doesn't connect meenter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxK2b.png)
[otra opción  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scw8J.jpg) I have tried to do several processes and I don't know why it doesn't connect.   help me please!

Comment: In the future, please include details about your issue in the question itself, and not in an image on another site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to connect to Cassandra on your local machine, on the default port of 9042.

If this is not working, I would check the following:

- Cassandra is indeed running on your local machine (verify with `nodetool status`).
- Either `listen_address` or `rpc_address` are bound to `localhost`. The address shown in the output of `nodetool status` is the address that should be used to connect.
- You are providing the correct username and password, if `CassandraAuthorizer` and `PasswordAuthenticator` are being used.
- You are providing the correct SSL/TLS certificate if client-to-node SSL is enabled.
- Also, as of Cassandra 4.0, connecting with client-to-node SSL enabled now happens on port 9142, while regular, unencrypted traffic is still on 9042.